# Trying to pause and resume goroutines using channels but eventually they hang up

Tags: go

I need to spwan multiple goroutines that make API calls to GitHub to get reviews of PRs for all repos of an org in batches. For example

```
{RepoA: #1, #2, ..........#20}
{RepoA: #21, #22, ..........#40}
.
.
{RepoZ: #1, #2, ..........#20}
```

This is my calling process

```
// get the heartbeats channel
heartbeats := signal.Heartbeats()
// get the run chasennel
run := signal.Run()
rem, _ := c.ghCollector.GetRemainingRequests(ctx)
// fill Signal.run chan with as many empty structs as there are github api requests left
signal.SetRun(rem)

// run all jobs
for _, batch := range batches {
        signal.RegisterTask() // this just increments a wait group counter
        c.ghCollector.GetReviewsWorker(ctx, batch, signal, heartbeats, run)
}

go func() {
            logging.Debug("infinite goroutine")
            for {
                select {
                case <-quit:
                    logging.Debug("all goroutines have exited, quit")
                    return

                case <-heartbeats:
                    logging.Debug("goroutines are running, skip the API Rate limit poll in default case")
                    continue

                default:
                 // get the number of requests remaining
                    if rem, _ := c.ghCollector.GetRemainingRequests(ctx); rem > 0 {
                        // fill the run channel with the remaining number of requests with empty structs
                        signal.SetRun(rem)
                    } else {
                        logging.Debug("none left")
                        // if requests are not available then loop again
                        heartbeats <- struct{}{}
                    }
                }
            }
        }()
       // wait for all the goroutines to be done and decrement the waitgroup counter
       signal.Wait()
       quit <- struct{}{}
```

This is the worker function

```
GetReviewsWorker(ctx context.Context, prs *types.PRBatch, signal *orchestrator.Signal, heartbeats chan struct{}, run <-chan struct{}) {
    go func() {
        // decrement wg
        defer signal.Done()
        for _, pr := prs.Batch {
           // run only if there are requests left 
           <-run
           // if running then send a heartbeat to indicate the worker is not idle/waiting
           heartbeats <- struct{}{}
           // do some work, make some API calls
        }
    }()
}
```

This is the signal struct

```
type Signal struct {
    run        chan struct{}
    heartbeats chan struct{}
    wg         sync.WaitGroup
}

func NewSignal(length int) *Signal {
    return &Signal{
        heartbeats: make(chan struct{}),
        // because send and receives from a nil channel block forever
        run: make(chan struct{}, length),
    }
}

func (s *Signal) SetRun(runs int) {
    // only send runs as many as the running tasks
    for i := 0; i < runs; i++ {
        logging.Debug("RUN RUN RUN ", i)
        s.run <- struct{}{}
    }
}

// other methods
//
```

I run this for an organization, which starts around 1000 goroutines and it works fine for some time but eventually, it hangs up and nothing is printed to the logs.

What am I doing wrong? My plan was to make an API call every time we have requests available by filling up the run chan with the number of remaining requests. If there is something in the channel then the execution will proceed otherwise it will block till the channel gets filled up again

In case it proceeds, a signal is sent to the heartbeat channel (which is there to avoid making a rate limit querying request to Github). If there is a heartbeat we know that the goroutine is doing some work and is not blocked so we just loop-select as usual without checking for remaining requests

Once all the goroutines are done we send the quit signal to stop the process of polling the Github API for rate limit and we are done.
I thought this would work fine but it only worked fine in my head.

EDIT: Adding some more details regarding the problem

So what I am trying to do is fetch the number of reviews on every PR for an organization using the graphql API. I have the number of PRs for every repo in small batches of lets say 20 as described at the top.

For every batch, I want to run my review worker which will fetch the number of reviews for that batch of PRs by making calls in a loop. This reviews worker runs for every batch in its own goroutine

Since Github has a rate limit of 5000 req/hr, I want to be able to fire up all my goroutines but as soon as I hit the rate limit I want them all to pause execution and wait till we have more requests available for that I am using channels with empty structs to indicate whether we have requests available or not this is the run chan when it is filled we go about our business when it is empty it blocks the running goroutines.

Before starting the review workers the code makes a call to github to see how many requests are avaiable, based on that number we fill the run chan with as many empty structs so that we can make as many api calls in our goroutines and then block.

Comment: Describe the problem that you are trying to solve in more detail.  The current description is brief and it's difficult to infer the problem from the code.

Comment: @CeriseLimón I have made an edit, please take a look

Comment: Thanks, that helps. See https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/time/rate.

Comment: @CeriseLimón the package expects token bucket to be filled at r tokens per scond but I only want the bucket to be filled when there are requests available not every second, not sure if I can use it to solve my problem

Comment: Divide the hourly rate limit by 3600 to get the per second rate limit: `limiter := rate.NewLimiter(5000.0 / 3600, 1)`.   Call `limiter.Wait(ctx)` before executing each API call.